# Group Introduction Fear

Tags: work-environment, motivation, stress, morale, anxiety

I have around 7 years of work experience and recently I found myself terrified with group introductions. It has never happened before. I am dreaded with so much fear that I feel I am a total mess.

I am software engineer and joined a company 2 years back, thinking of it as my dream job. It has been almost 1 1/2 years since I had worked on a proper project and gradually my confidence and morale has declined. Most of the time I am assigned with non-important tasks and pretty much I finish it off in 1-2 hours and rest of the week I am idle. Once, I did get to work on a good project but I was disappointed that even when I was able to complete the project with best outcome my morale and confidence was and is still low. I guess I have lost my motivation, confidence and the enthusiasm.

I guess I have lot of free time that I have indulged myself in negative thinking that I am now having panic attacks of going to trainings or group introductions.

I am thinking of changing jobs but I am worried that I will carry over my existing mindset to the new job. I am feeling so low that I feel inferior to my colleagues when I know I am really good at what I do. I have been reading self help books and it is of no use.

How to break this habit? I am losing my health and sleep. I want to feel confident again.

Comment: What's a group introduction (that's a honest question, by the way)? And why would going to training sessions cause you a panic attack - what's at stake in the process or the outcome that would put such fear into you? The one time I was this terrified is when my three favorite nieces came up to me and told me that they saw me as a role model and they wanted to be like me :)

Comment: How is your relationship wiith your managers and colleagues? Do they notice anything of your problem? Have you received any complaints or negative feedback about your performance? Do you have any idea of what may have started this negative spirale? Have you thought of seeking out professional help?

Comment: I would agree with Torok, from the tone of your post (you have no issues with anyone at your work yet still feel bad) it sounds more of a personal issue that a workplace problem. I would suggest looking for a psychologist, you might be suffering from depression or something like that.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan..Prolonged low self esteem and lack of self confidence has given me the opportunity to make mountains of mole-hills or I would prefer to say monsters of moles. Lack of belief in myself and negative experience during these sessions made me to believe they are indeed terrible experiences.

Comment: @PéterTörök..When I started, I felt that I could do more and when I did not get the opportunity or appreciated for whatever I was working on, I started to think negatively and was bitter with everyone at work. I was complaining about everything at work and constantly thinking about how miserable I was, even while at home. I was frustrated and had negative feelings for everyone. Once I realized that I started having my panic attacks, I have changed my attitude towards my colleagues and manager. Now I respect and treat them properly. There are no issues my performance.

Comment: @SureshKumar In other words, you created your own personal hell hole with your mind and in your mind - There were and are no real world negative consequences that accrue from the training sessions and the group introductions. You're right: you need to change your attitude not for the sake of changing your attitude but so that you can see the world differently and in a much more realistic, positive light. And seeing the world differently is critical to changing the way you live your life.

Comment: @SureshKumar He who see enemies everywhere and acts as if he has enemies everywhere - he will alienate enough people that he will actually have enemies everywhere. Fortunately, you are nowhere near that stage. I join others in recommending that you seek counseling to put your healing process on a stronger base and accelerate your healing.

Comment: If you can afford it, I highly suggest seeing a psychologist and/or therapist. The symptoms you mention seem very similar to depression, which is a very serious disease. A doctor may be able to help you to feel motivated and even happy again, and might even save your life.

Comment: Hi Suresh, If you can edit this post to focus on a more specific question, the edits will bump the post to the top for review. Posts seeking advice don't do so well on our Q&A site. See [ask] for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason you dread group introductions is because you have too much free time on the job and you may feel like you are not contributing to the level that your colleagues are. That is the real problem. In group introductions, people say who they are and what they do, and you have said that you complete your work quickly and are idle the rest of the week. If you address this problem (not enough work), group introductions will be much less stressful, because you will feel more like a contributor and your confidence will increase.

Ask your supervisor for additional work, and if you get that work I predict your anxiety about group introductions will go away.

Here is a sample introduction based on what you wrote:

> Hi, I am Suresh and I do unimportant work here for 1-2 hours per week, after which time I try to look busy.

Who wouldn't hate delivering this introduction?

Wouldn't it be better to say something like:

> Hi, I'm Suresh, and I work on the XYZ project. Before that I was involved in development work for the ABC project which you all remember fondly.

Whenever I was new on a team, group introductions bothered me, too. It always feels better to feel like a contributor.

Comment: Wow...you really hit the nail on the head. I have nothing important to say and most probably I am looking myself less than my colleagues at a subconscious level. At least I can take a more constructive path from now. Thanks!!!